# MySQL's decimal calculation inconsistency

Tags: mysql, decimal, precision, consistency

I'm using MySQL *Server version: 5.6.20-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1-log - (Ubuntu)* and having trouble with decimal calculation. Here's my case:

I'm having a table with decimal field `DECIMAL(65, 24)`. I need it to be precise since it holds monetary data. I also keep a conversion ratio for the different currencies of the same type (`DECIMAL(65, 24)`) so I can give the same price in other currencies. Such ratios are usually small like `0.000030769230769231000000`.

The problem arises when I try to aggregate some of the prices, if and only if I write it this way:

```
SELECT SUM(price * conversion_rate), COUNT(DISTINCT some_field)
FROM products
GROUP BY some_other_field
```

And the problem is that the result is not consistent! I mean when I re-run the query the results change! Usually it changes among two cases and it seems random. And the change is considerable, e.g. `Case1 - Case2 = $7,025.13`! (of course it depends on the prices and the number of products). The problem is resolved if I omit the `DISTINCT` or the `COUNT` function.

And MySQL says [this about decimal data-type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These
>   types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for
>   example with monetary data.

Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: What is the data-type of the price field?

Comment: Both are `DECIMAL(65, 24)`

Comment: Show some example data so we can try to repro what you're asking about.

Comment: I was thinking maybe sum() is returning a different data type and thus rounding the result, but apparently they fixed that in 5.0.5.

Comment: @JGrice that's actually a good guess, and possibly a correct one,  since the PO provided (if I'm not mistaken) only his OS version, not MySQL version.

Comment: @Kleskowy No, it's the MySQL server version as OP stated.

Comment: What is the type of the `DISTINCT some_field`? Because changing that will keep the results persistent, the problem is not with the `SUM()` part. My best guess is that the `DISTINCT some_field` is changing and you are comparing the wrong data.

Comment: @HugoDelsing The data and conditions of the different runs remain constant at all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for my rushed question. There is a bug but it has nothing to do with MySQL or decimals. I've tested my scenario in MySQL's console and also MySQL Workbench and none of them showed any inconsistency. So I'm concluding that the problem relies in PhpMyAdmin (or in PHP for that matter) where I tested my first scenario in. But the test case remains valid if you use PhpMyAdmin, the results will be changing from one run to another (in test case explained above) which amazed me after such a hard working day, resulted in a rushed question.

PhpMyAdmin's version: 4.2.7deb0.1

PHP's version: 5.5.16-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1